# angularjs: how to prevent from processing additional directives after ng-hide

Tags: angularjs

I have some code that is running twice even thou angularJs is rendering only one branch of it.

```
<div ng-Show="SomeCondition">
...
</div>
<div ng-Hide="SomeCondition">
...
</div>
```

AngularJs is correctly only rendering one of the divs, however it's processing both.  This is leading to some performance degredation as each section is quite big. Is there a way to remove processing from one of the branch of execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is `ng-switch`, which will 'Conditionally change the DOM structure.' This means that the other cases will not be run, unlike using ng-hide/ng-show, which just adjust CSS.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch

```
<div ng-switch on="SomeCondition">
    <div ng-switch-when="true">Example</div>
    <span ng-switch-when="false">Example Two</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="somethingElse">Example Three</span>
    <span ng-switch-default>default</span>
  </div>
```